# How to replace the driver of realtek 8111/8169 NIC to 8111/8168

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, scientific-linux

I have a Scientific Linux 6.2 with a kernel version 2.6.32-220.4.1 installed and I got a problem with a realtek r8111/8168 NIC. I found that this card does not work properly with the driver r8169, so I am downgrading to r8168 and I found this site of how to do it in Debian, Ubuntu and Mint:
http://www.makeinstall.es/2011/06/problemas-con-realtek-rtl81118168b.html

I downloaded the driver from the Realtek site: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false
called r8168-8.037.00. The problem starts when I want to compile the autorun.sh script because it appears the following message:

> Check old driver and unload it.
>
> rmmod 8169
>
> Build the module and install
>
> make: ** /lib/modules/2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64/build: No such file or directory. Stop.

The worst part is that once this script is executed I lost the connectivity of my wired connection.

The solution could be to create the folder called **build** in /lib/modules/2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64/ but I cannot do it because I found inside of folder 2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64 that there is this link:

> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root **build** -> ../../../usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64

I remark that **build** appears in the terminal as highlighted with black and with a red font.

Even if I try to type mkdir build the terminal says:

> cannot create directory 'build': File exists

My questions are:

1. How can I create this build directory in order to run the autorun.sh script so I get the NIC working?
2. What is the meaning of the highlighted with red font **build** file?
3. I read that this realtek NIC has caused a lot of problems to Linux users when trying to install the driver. Do you recommend to me to just change this NIC for another?

Comment: You seem to miss the linux headers. You will have to download and install them for your distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I wasn't able to compile the driver was because I was running and old kernel version. What I did was to type:

> yum -y update

Then I executed the autorun.sh script and it generated the following code of successfulness:

> Check old driver and unload it.
>
> rmmod r8168
>
> Build the module and install
>
> DEPMOD 2.6.32.-431.1.2.el6.x86_64
>
> Completed

However, the card is not detected by the system. The driver is loaded because I typed :

> lspci -v

and it generated the following log:

> Kernel driver in use: r8168
>
> Kernel modules: r8168

Now, I am looking for any solution to detect the NIC.

Answer (score 0):

For your first two questions:

1. You need the kernel development package ([apparently](https://www.scientificlinux.org/documentation/faq/sl4x) `kernel-devel`).
2. It likely means a broken symbolic link (i.e. the link's target doesn't exist).  You can check it with `file build`.